# How to understand the transition function of Turing Machines?

Tags: computer-science, turing-machines

I am going through a lecture on Turing Machines and am confused by the use of notations for the transition state function.

The transition function is defined as
$$ Q\times\sum \rightarrow (\sum \cup \{ L,R\}) \times Q$$

Where Q is the set of states, $\sum$= tape alphabets, and $\sum \cup \{ L,R\}$ is the set of actions. Does the times symbol, X, here mean the cartesian product? If so, why is the cartesian product used here?

If I undertand this correctly, $Q \times \sum$ is a function that is being mapped to $(\sum \cup \{ L,R\}) \times Q$?

Thanks!

Comment: Given a state and a letter, you get an action and a new state. That is, given a pair $(q,b)$ where $q$ is a state and $b$ we get a pair, $(a,q'),$ where $a$ is the action and $q'$ is a state. The Cartesian product is just ordered pairs.

Comment: Since $Q$ and $\Sigma$ are sets $\times$ will be the cartesian product. I've never seen any deviation from that standard.

Comment: There is another common model, where it would be $Q\times \Sigma\to \Sigma\times \{L,R\}\times Q.$ In this model, you always move left or right after each step, after writing a letter to the cell. But in the model you are given, the "write letter" and "move" steps are considered individual actions. It's not hard to map one model to the other.